# Get ID of submitted record after save in AngularJS Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript

Basically, here's my controller:

```
class Api::ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_params, only: [:show]

  respond_to :json


  def new
    @project = Project.new
    render layout: false
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new allowed_params
    @project.sample = false
    @project.users << current_user

    if @project.save
      @project.members << current_user
      # redirect_to project_path(@project)

    else
    end

    render json: {new_project: @project}

  end

    def set_params
      @page   = params[:page]
      @client = params[:client]
      @block  = params[:block]
      @block  = Block.find @block if @block
    end

    def allowed_params
      params.require(:project).permit :name, :sample
    end 
end
```

This is my html snippet:

```
<form ng-submit='createStream()'>
   <input autofocus='autofocus' class='form-control' id='project_name' placeholder='Untitled Stream' required='required' type='text', ng-model='newProject.name'>
   <br/>
   <input type='submit' value='Create' class='btn btn-md btn-success'>
</form>
```

My popovercontroller.js.coffee

```
App.controller("PopoverCtrl", ($scope, Project, $location, $http) ->
    $scope.initializeProject = ->
        $scope.newProject = new Project();
    $scope.createStream = ->
        project = Project.save($scope.newProject)
        $scope.projects.push(project)
)
```

And the services/factory

```
App.factory 'Project', ($resource) ->
  $resource "/api/projects/:id", {id: @id},
    query:
      method: "POST"
      isArray: false
```

I can save data into my DB, but I want to redirect to the show view after saving the data.

Just like the default scaffolding for RAILS, wherein after submitting the form given that it is valid... it will redirect to its show page . (e.g. `localhost:3000/projects/1` with its ID.

However, the behavior now is that after submitting the form, it's not redirecting to the show page. I'm trying to get the ID of the saved record but no luck.

I tried putting `$location.path('/projects/' + @id)` but seems like `@id` is undefined and not being recognized. I'm new in manipulating JSON using Angular.

**EDIT:** Here's my console logs. I think JSON isn't returning? It redirects to the page where I came from. My form is in popover style so no redirection has been made.

```
Started POST "/api/projects" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-30 06:38:30 +0800
Processing by Api::ProjectsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"name"=>"XXX", "project"=>{"name"=>"XXX"}}
  User Load (2.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 14 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `projects` (`created_at`, `name`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-01-29 22:38:30', 'XXX', '2014-01-29 22:38:30')
   (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `projects_users` (`project_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (91, 14)
   (16.4ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `project_memberships` (`member_id`, `project_id`) VALUES (14, 91)
   (1.2ms)  COMMIT
Completed 200 OK in 53ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 22.3ms)


Started GET "/projects/23" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-30 06:38:30 +0800


Started GET "/?goto=projects/23" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-30 06:38:30 +0800
Processing by MainController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"goto"=>"projects/23"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 14 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered main/index.html.haml within layouts/main (0.1ms)
  Rendered application/_header.html.slim (0.5ms)
  Rendered application/_footer.html.slim (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 40ms (Views: 36.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```